# how to retrieve html5 form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am working on a html5 form.

am having problems when it comes on retrieving values from drop down lists,time and values that have spaces.

for drop down lists | are converted to %7C,
for time : are converted to %3A and AM or PM are not shown while spaces are converted to +.
is there a way to retrieve the form values exactly the way they appear to the users.

if i will be forced to convert them to there original values using regular expression,which ones will work for the above problems

am new to jquery so spare me if there is any ambiguity in my question
thanks in advance.

below is a sample code of my project.

```
 **switch (questionType) {
        case "VTFH44UF34F4FH3": //textbox 
            $('#variables').append($('<input id="' + variableID + '" name="' + variableID + '" required type="text" data-mini="true"  placeholder=""/>'));
            $('#variables').trigger('create');
            break;
}**
```

above code is how am creating controls dynamically.

```
 **function showValues() {       
    var str = $("form").serialize();
     str  = str .split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < str .length; i++) {
        var str2  = str [i].split("=");
        var name = str2  [0];
        var value = str2   [1];
    }      
}  
showValues();
```

}**

above code is how am getting the form values

Comment: Can you show some of your source code?

Comment: The values are being URL encoded, which is entirely normal. Is this causing you a problem on the server side?

Comment: am working on an offline project,so i need to collect the form values to save them to the local storage first before syncing to the server later.

Answer (score 0):

here is the output of:

```
encodeURI('aaa bbb ccc 10.10.12|') => "aaa%20bbb%20ccc%2010.10.12%7C"
```

in order to get the original value execute:

```
decodeURI('aaa%20bbb%20ccc%2010.10.12%7C') =>  "aaa bbb ccc 10.10.12|"
```

use those methods:

```
encodeURI()
decodeURI()
```

Comment: @jsexpert..thanks for the reply.i have tested using these two methods but it doesnt decode everything.....in my example it only decodes the | character but not the : and space.why cant it decode everything??